# Swift: DispatchQueue.global

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, queue

I am writing an app that always use dispatchQueue to help me handle packet received from another devices.

Hence, in my code, depends on the packet received, it will trigger codes like:

```
if (// condition fulfilled) {

 let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default)
 queue.async { () -> Void in
 self.handlePacket(packet: packet) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       // do something.
    }
  }
}
```

}

Then I found that when one part of the code with the same variable "queue" is executed, another part code can be triggered without calling. And the app crash at the line queue.async { () -> Void in

Is that I cannot use the same name for the queue? Or my code actually mess up those queues?

Please advise.

Comment: Help us help you! Include the code that crashed and the error message

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should ask yourself, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is `handlePacket(_)` too heavy to process it on current queue?

Concurrency is hard, and you should try to avoid it, until you realize how does concurrency and queues work in iOS.